# S3FS: TypeError: can't concat bytes to str

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3

**fs.S3fs** seems to be not compatible with python 3 in the passing of `prefix` variable.

Here is my code(I am trying to list the directory of mybucket):

```
import fs.s3fs
myfs = fs.s3fs.S3FS(bucket, prefix, aws_access_ke, aws_secret_key)
myfs.listdir()
```

It is producing an error in (fs/s3fs.py line 180) so I tried doing a:

```
prefix += chr(i%256).encode('utf-8')
```

to fix it. But the error now goes to:

```
path = self._separator.join(iteratepath(path))
```

Comment: What version of `fs` are you using?

Comment: @TomDalton It's '0.5.2'

Comment: What was the original error? Is this the same file you're using https://github.com/PyFilesystem/pyfilesystem/blob/master/fs/s3fs.py ?

Comment: Looks like it's not compatible - see https://github.com/PyFilesystem/pyfilesystem/blob/master/fs/s3fs.py#L5

Comment: Since AFAIK Boto now does work for python 3, I expect the fs project would gratefully accept pull requests to fix your issue!

Comment: yes @TomDalton same file. That's why I am finding a fix for it.

Comment: You're asking us to fix the `fs.s3fs` package to be python3 compatible?

Comment: No @TomDalton, I think what's producing my error is the prefix variable. So I am trying to fix the above error.

Comment: OK. It would probably be helpful if you could include the value you're passing for `prefix`, and the full stacktrace/error that you get - though I suspect the answer is still going to be that the package itself needs updating to support python 3 (?for a non-empty `prefix`?).